# QT - xml file -- not modifing text node content

Tags: qt

My xml routines :-----

```
int MainWindow::xmlOpenFile()
{
    //set the name of the file
    xmlFile.setFileName(xmlFileName);

    // open read & write mode
    if (!xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Text))
    {
        return FAIL_TO_OPEN_FILE;
    }

    // Assign file to the stream
    xmlStream = new QTextStream(&xmlFile);

    xmlDomDocument.setContent(&xmlFile);

    return SUCCESS_TO_OPEN_FILE;
}

void MainWindow::xmlAddRoot()
{
    // Make the root element
    xmlRoot = xmlDomDocument.createElement(ROOT_ELEMENT_DETAILS);

    // Add it to the document
    xmlDomDocument.appendChild(xmlRoot);
}

void MainWindow::xmlCreateNode(QDomElement &NodeElement, QString Name)
{
    // Make the node element
    NodeElement = xmlDomDocument.createElement(Name);

}

void MainWindow::xmlAddTextNode(QDomElement &NodeElement, QString textContent)
{
    QDomText textNode;
    textNode = xmlDomDocument.createTextNode(textContent);
    NodeElement.appendChild(textNode);
}

void MainWindow::xmlAppendNode(QDomElement &xmlParent, QDomElement &xmlChild)
{
    xmlParent.appendChild(xmlChild);

}
```

This my program to enter text in `empty` XML file, `MyXML.xml` :----

```
xmlFileName = "D:/Temp/MyXML.xml";

xmlOpenFile();
xmlAddRoot();

xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNode, "hello");
xmlAddTextNode(xmlTempNode, "hi" );
xmlAppendNode(xmlRoot,xmlTempNode);

xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNode, "hello 0");
xmlAddTextNode(xmlTempNode, "hi 0" );
xmlAppendNode(xmlRoot,xmlTempNode);

xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNode, "hello -1");
xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNodeChild, "hello -1 - 1");
xmlAddTextNode(xmlTempNodeChild, "hi -1 - 1" );
xmlAppendNode(xmlTempNode,xmlTempNodeChild);
xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNodeChild, "hello -1 - 2");
xmlAddTextNode(xmlTempNodeChild, "hi -1 - 2" );
xmlAppendNode(xmlTempNode,xmlTempNodeChild);
xmlAppendNode(xmlRoot,xmlTempNode);

xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNode, "hello -2");
xmlAddTextNode(xmlTempNode, "hi -2" );
xmlAppendNode(xmlRoot,xmlTempNode);

// Here i am replacingthe node, hello -1 
QDomNode temp_1 = xmlRoot.firstChild().nextSibling().nextSibling();
QDomNode temp = temp_1;
QDomElement element = temp.toElement();
QDomNode n = element.firstChild();
QDomText t = n.toText();
t.setData("Here is the new text");

//Replace node "hello -1"
xmlRoot.replaceChild(temp,temp_1);

xmlCloseFile();
```

Here in above code i made 4 nodes `to root` Test Cases then i modified the 3rd child `xmlRoot.firstChild().nextSibling().nextSibling();` , but changes are not reflected in final xml file

It created following xml file :----

```
<Test Cases>
 <hello>hi</hello>
 <hello 0>hi 0</hello 0>
 <hello -1>
  <hello -1 - 1>hi -1 - 1</hello -1 - 1>
  <hello -1 - 2>hi -1 - 2</hello -1 - 2>
 </hello -1>
 <hello -2>hi -2</hello -2>
</Test Cases>
```

but i want to replace `"hello -1"` node with  :---

```
 <hello -1>
  <hello -1 - 1>Here is the new text</hello -1 - 1>
  <hello -1 - 2>hi -1 - 2</hello -1 - 2>
 </hello -1>
```

Why replace child is not working `?`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :---

```
QDomNode temp_1 = xmlRoot.firstChild().nextSibling().nextSibling();
QDomElement temp;

xmlCreateNode(temp,"hello -1");
xmlCreateNode(xmlTempNodeChild, "hello -1 - 1");
xmlAddTextNode(xmlTempNodeChild, "Here is the new text" );
xmlAppendNode(temp,xmlTempNodeChild);
xmlRoot.replaceChild(temp,temp_1);
```